# Backbone fetch() will not populate models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Trying to fetch data but its not populating the models, here is what i have

```
House = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'http://localhost:3000/account/view/house',
    idAttribute: "_id",
    initialize: function(){
        this.on("create", function(){ console.log('Created house') })
    }
})

HousesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: House, 
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/account/view/houses'
})

housesCollection = new HousesCollection()

housesCollection.fetch() //to grab the json

//I actually go to network panel to see if it completes and it does then i try to show them


housesCollection.models // shows an empty array which means the pulled data didnt populate the models
```

If i look in the network tab, I see it successfully pulled the proper data.

Here is the response:

```
[
  {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "51e4a10f6357a5a015000004",
    "address": "17900 Opp",
    "buildingName": "S. End Build",
    "city": "NY",
    "modified_date": "2013-07-16T01:25:35.032Z",
    "creation_date": "2013-07-16T01:25:35.032Z"
  },
  {
    "buildingName": "North Building",
    "address": "17900 Kingslane",
    "city": "Detroit",
    "_id": "51e63f13f3924fa413000004",
    "__v": 0,
    "modified_date": "2013-07-17T06:52:03.670Z",
    "creation_date": "2013-07-17T06:52:03.670Z"
  }
]
```

Any idea why its not populating the models?

**EDIT: adding my overrode backbone sync**

```
APP.ajaxSettings = {
    "crossDomain": true
  , "xhrFields": {withCredentials:true}
  , "statusCode": { //Tell jQuery to watch for any 401 or 403 errors and handle them appropriately
        401: function(){console.log('401') },// Redirect the to the login page.
        403: function(){console.log('403') } // 403 -- Access denied
    }
}

APP.sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
  // Update other options here.
    options = ORTO.ajaxSettings

    options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    };

  APP.sync(method, model, options);
};
```

Comment: `fetch` is an AJAX call, you need to wait for the server to respond before looking for the data. Bind to the appropriate events, use the jQuery promise that's returned, add a success handler, ...

Comment: I get that part, it responded, that's how i got the json. So at that point i should have the models in memory and I don't for some reason.

Comment: Have you added a error and success callbacks to the `fetch` call? Have you tried adding a `parse` to your collection to see what it is getting fed?

Comment: Only thing i did was override Backbone.sync, i added in to the post. Not sure what to do with adding 'parse', can you elaborate?

Comment: Did you try to log in the success callback of the fetch request `houseCollections.fetch({ success: function() {console.log(houseCollections.models) } })`

Comment: yes and nothing returns. i see the request in the network tab though

Comment: Actually, you should use `houseCollcetions.fetch().done(...)`

Comment: i dont think its an issue with the callback, the fact that i see the request in the network panel shows the information was pulled

Comment: Are you really throwing out the `options` and replacing them with your own?

Comment: It should had been extended...

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a response and can successfully see your models as a json response, the below should work

```
var House = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'http://localhost:3000/account/view/house',
    idAttribute: "_id"
})

var HousesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: House, 
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/account/view/houses'
})

var housesCollection = new HousesCollection(),
    req = housesCollection.fetch();

req.done(function() {
    console.log(housesCollection.models);
});

req.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the options when i should had extended it

```
APP.sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
  // Update other options here.

    //options = ORTO.ajaxSettings // this is wrong
    _.extend(options, ORTO.ajaxSettings)// this is right

    options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    };

  APP.sync(method, model, options);
};
```